# How to pass variable to a views template?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have this in my template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
$vars['test'] = 'Filtertest';
}
```

And this in my views-view-responsive-grid--taxonomy-term.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $test; ?>
```

... this does not work though. The template is called and works but my $test variable does not get printed.

What am I missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's better to check first on view name like `if($vars['view']->name == 'your_view_name') { $vars['test'] = 'Filtertest';  }` , and make sure that  `views-view-responsive-grid--taxonomy-term.tpl.php` the right tpl for this view, and flush all caches

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have changed that now, The template is called and works, so i suppose it should be possible to pass variables to it?

Comment: To variable to view tpl `$vars['test'] = 'Filtertest';` should works, just be sure that you in the right tpl .

Comment: berramou: I finally got it to work by changing the template filename to a shorter name and using the exact same name in the preprocess function. See my answer below. Thank's for helping.

Comment: great, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this, with your function

```
public static function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $vars['test'] = 'Filtertest';
  return $vars['test'] ;
}
```

Then use this short code on your twig view:

```
{{ test }}
```

or if wanna use it in something.php in your views:

```
dump(test )
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else have the same problem. Changing the name of the template file to `views-view-responsive-grid.tpl.php` and then using that same name in the preprocess function in `template.php`, like this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_responsive_grid(&$vars) {
  if($vars['view']->name == 'taxonomy_term') {
    $vars['test'] = 'Filtertest';
  }
}
```

... fixed the problem. Now the $test variable is printed. Apparently the template's filename can't be too specific.